# React Navigation - Navigating between different StackNavigators with protected view

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

Sorry if there is an obvious solution to this but I don't find the documentation for react-navigation to be very clear which is frustrating as it's now being presented as the official react-native navigation library.

In my index file I call asynstorage to retrieve an access token generated on login. Then I want to either return a protected stack if logged in or the welcome stack if not.

```
render() {
if (this.state.isLoggedin === true) {
  return <Protected />;
}
else {
  return <Root />;
}

}
```

Here is my router

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
Welcome: { screen: Welcome },
Login: { screen: Login },
Register: { screen: Register }
});

export const Protected = StackNavigator({
Conversations: { screen: Conversations }
});
```

This is working when I reload the app. What I don't understand is how to navigate from "Root" to "Protected" on press, I don't want these routes in the same StackNavigator. Is there a way to do this or do I need to change the entire structure and have both Root and Protected under one stacknavigator?

Again sorry if this is obvious but i've built a chat app using the react native Navigator before it was deprecated and didn't find it nearly as confusing. I feel that there should be better documentation and examples of how a real world app should be structured.

Answer (score 0):

you can navigation a other page with this.props.navigation.navigate('otherView'), for example review, that next example navigato to a page Chat
App.js

```
class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

    class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this routes was defined, in this have Chat a where want navigate

```
 const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
      Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
      Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    });
```

Warning if you are doing a login verify the subject that after being logged in the user could give back and return to the login, it would be advisable to reset the routes when logging in

```
this.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
           {
              index: 0,
              actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home', params: {param: data},})
              ]
            }));
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I understand I can put the Root and Protected views inside a main stack navigator and just hide the back button but have heard there are issues with the android back button doing that, and I don't think I really understand what reset is doing and read a few github issues about it so wanted to see if there was a better way. I was hoping I could just do something like 'this.navigation.navigate(Protected)' or 'this.navigation.navigate(Conversations)' from Root, but I guess that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with you, React Navigation's documentation can be very confusing. Unforutnately Navigators don't provide a direct way to pass down props to child components. For this case, you unfortunately need to use an escape hatch, basically a common module that allows you to connect the components to each other. Instead of advising you to write this complicated component on your own, I would strongly suggest using redux. Even though it requires some boilerplate but it would allow you to connect all components to the same state, so in your main component class the isLoggedIn variable would immediately change when the Login or Register components change it using redux actions. I would suggest reading the redux documentation and getting started with it. You basically create a redux store with just the user authentication in it and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed yea I was thinking of using redux when things got more complicated but I guess I should just implement it now that sounds like a good solution as ill most likely need it eventually anyway. Thanks!